# How to do this with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

```
<strong>title</strong>

<cite>...</cite>
<cite>...</cite>
...
<a>ank</a>
```

I want to append a new element `$el` right behind the last `<cite>` behind `<strong>`,if there is no `<cite>`,then append `$el` right after `<strong>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$last_cite = $("strong ~ cite:last");

if ($last_cite.length > 0) {
  $last_cite.after($el);
} else {
  $("strong").after($el);
}
```

[EDIT]

> ~ Selects all sibling elements that
>   follow after the "prev" element, have
>   the same parent, and match the
>   filtering "siblings" selector.
>   [source](http://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/)

[/EDIT]

Or in one line but not really shorter and less readable:

```
$el.insertAfter($last_cite.length > 0 ? $last_cite : $("strong"));
```

**UPDATE**

shorter approach:

```
$el.insertAfter($("strong, strong ~ cite:last").eq(-1))
```

Comment: `$('strong, strong ~ cite').filter(':last').after($el)`? Probably less efficient, but more readable.

Comment: What does `~` mean in `strong ~ cite:last` ?

Comment: On second thought, this has the same potential problem as the `nextAll()` solution.

Comment: @Tgr: You're right about the potential problem, but it depends on how to interpret the question. I think wamp needs to clearify question, before we can make the right answer

Comment: @Tgr, yes you are right, but the dom structure in my case is easy enough so that case won't happen,so I accepted it:)

Answer (score 0):

```
var cites = $('strong').nextAll('cite');
/*Incorrect
if (cites.length==0) $('strong').append($el);
else cites.filter(':last').append($el);
*/
```

Notepad code. Sorry I made a mistake.

**EDIT:**
if-else can be changed to:

```
$el.insertAfter(cites.length==0?$('strong'):cites.filter(':last'));
```

Comment: insertAfter is not the same as append! Your first snippet will create will create this `<strong>title{$el}</strong>` if there are no cites and you second snippet will create `<strong>title</strong>{$el}`, and
`<cite>...{$el}</cite>` versus `<cite>...</cite>{$el}`

Comment: `nextAll` selects all `cite` tags after the `strong`, not just the immediately following ones.

Comment: @Tgr - "after strong" is exactly what he want, isn't it?

Comment: not fully clear from the question, but I don't think so. Consider `<strong /><cite /><a>ank</a><cite />`

Answer (score 0):

```
var anchor = $('strong');
while (anchor.next('cite').length) {
  anchor = anchor.next();
}
anchor.after($el);
```